# getActivityResult() intent parameter gives null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-camera

good morning sir,
I have used Navigation drawer and fragment.
i'm using  ActionBarActivity and in which i have called this Fragment.
in my Fragment i capture image from camera so in getActivityResult() method not give me Intent values.

```
package com.ssoft.admin.imageprocessingwithnavigation;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CameraDemo extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageButton mImgBtnActivityBack,mImgBtnActivityWrong,mImgBtnActivityRight ,mImgBtnActivityEdit ,mImgBtnActivitySearch ,mImgBtnActivityAdd ,mImgBtnActivityNext,mImgBtnActivitySetting;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout1,mLinearLayout2;
    Button mFragSignatureClear,mBtnBlack,mBtnRed,mSIBtnSubmit,mSIBtnCamera,mSIBtnAdd ;
    PaintView mPaintView;
    int currrID = 0;
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment;
    public int st = 3;
    int sizex, sizeh;
    Paint paint = new Paint() ;
    Uri imageUri=null ;
    final int CAMERA_DATA = 1888, INTENT_DATA = 1 ;
    Bitmap mbkground ;
    public CameraDemo() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mbkground = null ;
        mLinearLayout2=(LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.draw);
        mPaintView = new PaintView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mLinearLayout2.addView(mPaintView);
        mFragSignatureClear=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragSignatureClear);
        mFragSignatureClear.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnBlack=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.black);
        mBtnBlack.setOnClickListener(this);
        mBtnRed=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.red);
        mBtnRed.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSIBtnSubmit=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragSIBtnSubmit);
        mSIBtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSIBtnCamera=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera) ;
        mSIBtnCamera.setOnClickListener(this) ;
        mSIBtnAdd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add) ;
        mSIBtnAdd . setOnClickListener( this );
        DisplayMetrics m = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        int w = m.widthPixels;
        int h = m.heightPixels;

        sizex = w;
        sizeh = h;

        Log.i("hi", "" + sizex);
        Log.i("hi", "" + sizeh);
        Log.i("hi", "" + density);
        float fsize = sizex / density;

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.black){
            currrID=v.getId();
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.black){
            currrID=v.getId();
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.fragSIBtnSubmit){
            mPaintView.toJPEGFile();
            mPaintView.SaveFile();
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.camera){
                captureImage();
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.add){
            mPaintView.loadFromFile();
        }

        else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "FragSIPhotos Add Button OnClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    class Point {
        float x, y;

        public String toString() {
            return x + "," + y;
        }
    }
    public class LineData {
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

        LineData(List<Point> p) {
            points.addAll(p);
        }

        public void Draw(Canvas mCanvas, Paint paint) {
            float fData[] = new float[points.size() * 4];
            int Index = 0;
            for (Point point : points) {
                if (Index > 0) {
                    fData[Index++] = point.x;
                    fData[Index++] = point.y;
                }
                fData[Index++] = point.x;
                fData[Index++] = point.y;
                // canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);

            }
            if (Index > 2)
                mCanvas.drawLines(fData, 0, Index - 2, paint);

        }
    }
    public class PaintView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
        private static final String TAG = "PaintView" ;
        Paint paint = new Paint() ;
        int t = 0 ;
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>() ;
        List<LineData> pointsred = new ArrayList<LineData>() ;
        List<LineData> pointsblack = new ArrayList<LineData>() ;
        public PaintView(Context context) {
            super(context) ;
            setFocusable(true) ;
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true) ;
            List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>() ;

            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) ;
            this.setOnTouchListener(this) ;
            mbkground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.plain) ;

            paint.setAntiAlias(true) ;
            paint.setStrokeMiter(10.0f) ;
            paint.setStrokeWidth(st) ;

            currrID = R.id.red ;

        }
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas mCanvas) {
            mCanvas.drawBitmap(mbkground, 0, 0, null);
            // canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE) ;
            this.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            // To Do Paint for text
            //this code for  my image app
            //yesss very good
        /*    Paint mText= new Paint(Color.RED);
            mText.setTextSize(25);
            mCanvas.drawText("Hiren",100,100,mText);
        */    if (currrID == R.id.red)
                paint.setColor(Color.RED) ;
            else if (currrID == R.id.black)
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK) ;
            else
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK) ;

            float fdata[] = new float[points.size() * 4] ;
            int Index = 0 ;
            for (Point point : points) {
                if (Index > 0) {
                    fdata[Index++] = point.x ;
                    fdata[Index++] = point.y ;
                }
                fdata[Index++] = point.x ;
                fdata[Index++] = point.y ;
                // canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);

            }
            if (Index > 2)
                mCanvas.drawLines(fdata, 0, Index - 2, paint);

            paint.setColor(Color.RED) ;
            for (LineData lines : pointsred)
                lines.Draw(mCanvas, paint) ;


            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK) ;
            for (LineData lines : pointsblack)
                lines.Draw(mCanvas, paint) ;

            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE) ;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                points.clear() ;
            } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                {
                    LineData data = new LineData(points) ;

                    if (currrID == R.id.red)
                        pointsred.add(data) ;
                    else if (currrID == R.id.black)
                        pointsblack.add(data) ;

                    points.clear() ;
                }
            } else {

                Point point = new Point() ;

                point.x = event.getX() ;

                point.y = event.getY() ;

                points.add(point) ;
            }
            invalidate() ;

            return true;

        }
        public void toJPEGFile() {
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Mateco/") ;

            if (!folder.exists())
                folder.mkdirs() ;
            try {

                this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true) ;

                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Mateco/" + "Mateco" + ".png") ;
                // file mFile = new File(Environment.g)
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f) ;

                Bitmap bitmap = this.getDrawingCache() ;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, fos) ;
                // 80 quality bet 0-100 define

                fos.flush() ;
                fos.close() ;
                this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false) ;

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace() ;
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace() ;
            }

        }

        public void loadFromFile() {

            FileInputStream in;
            BufferedInputStream buf;

            try {
                in = new FileInputStream(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Mateco/"
                                + "mateco" + ".jpg");
                buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);

                mbkground = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);

                if (in != null) {
                    in.close();
                }
                if (buf != null) {
                    buf.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
            }
        }

        public void setBitMap(){

           /* mbkground = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.background) ;
*/
        }
        public void setBitMap(Bitmap photo){

            mbkground = photo;
        }

        public void SaveFile() {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Save 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Mateco/");

            if (!folder.exists())
                folder.mkdirs();
            try {
                this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                t++;
                File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Mateco/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Bitmap bitmap = this.getDrawingCache();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
                // 80 quality bet 0-100 define

                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
                File temp = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/Mateco/" + "Mateco" + ".png");
                temp.delete();
                this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"FILE_NOT_FOUND_EXCEPTION  "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"IO_EXCEPTION  "+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                File f = new File(
                        "file://"
                                + Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES));
                Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                getActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Save 9",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                getActivity().getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://"
                                + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Save 11",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
    public void captureImage(){
        // Define the file-name to save photo taken by Camera activity

        String fileName = "Mateco.jpg";

        // Create parameters for Intent with filename

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
        // Log.e("Intrenal Storage "+MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString(),"");

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION,"Image capture by camera");

        // imageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage

        Uri imageUri = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
      /*  Uri imageUri=getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert( MediaStore. Images. Media. INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,values ) ;
*/
        /**** EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI : style URI for the "primary" external storage volume. ****/


        // Standard Intent action that can be sent to have the camera
        // application capture an image and return it.

        Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, INTENT_DATA);
        Log.e("captureImage()", "state -1");
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_DATA);
        Log.e("captureIma   ge()", "end");

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "1");
        try {
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_DATA && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
                Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "2");

                InputStream stream =getActivity().getApplicationContext(). getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                mbkground = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "2.1");

                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "2.2");

                mPaintView.setBitMap(photo);
                Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "3");
            } else {
                // Image capture failed, advise user
                Log.e("OnActivityResult()", "5");
            }
        }catch (Exception objException){
            Log.e("onActivityResult();",""+objException.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're calling `getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_DATA)`, the hosting activity will receive the result. Have you tried calling it without `getActivty()`? That way your fragment should get the result.

Comment: Mr.MH i will try you suggestion but it not worked it also give null values in Intent

Comment: @HirenVaghela: where you are using `getActivityResult()` ??

Comment: Activity which is hosting you fragment will get the intent and desired result. You should implement 'onActivityResult' in that activity and save the result somewhere common object and then access that anywhere you want.

Comment: I have used onActivityResult() in Fragment

Answer (score 0):

This line is not returning what you think:

```
            InputStream stream =getActivity().getApplicationContext(). getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
```

It returns a URI if you do what you did on these lines:

```
            Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
```

But you didn't, so it will not return what you expect. You need to get the `ImageURL` by getting the URI as you stored it, like this:

```
            InputStream stream =getActivity().getApplicationContext(). getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getStringExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT));
```

EDIT:

Also, `startActivityForResult` is used to call a new `Activity` which, when it "finishes" will do a callback to it's calling `Activity`'s method `onActivityResult` - so that part of your code is probably also causing problems. You should be able to sort through it now though...

Comment: openInputStream() required Uri as a parameter.

Comment: yes - and `data.getData()` returns a URI if the proper attributes are set. I did not state my response properly.

Comment: hello sir any one have solution please helpme